# Prometheus Cloudwatch-Exporter not able to fetch metrics from Amazon AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

New to Prometheus, trying to configure cloudwatch-exporter to pull metrics from AWS account.
Exporter is running elb.yml to pull test load balancer metrics but not able to fetch anything.

Can someone guide me what could be wrong?
Attached config for reference.

[-Prometheus cloudwatch-exporter Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBu8y.jpg)

Comment: Having same problem- IAM role has cloudwatch:ListMetrics and cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics permissions but no metrics on /metrics endpoint. 

Were you able to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to monitor Application Load Balancer, not a deprecated Classic one, use this configuration

```
---
region: us-east-1
metrics:
- aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
  aws_metric_name: HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count
  aws_dimensions: [AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer, TargetGroup]
  aws_statistics: [Sum]
```